# Pandas-way to separate a DataFrame based on previouse groupby() explorations without loosing the not-grouped columns

Tags: pandas

I tried to translate the problem with my real data to example data presented in my question. Maybe I just have a simple technical problem. Or maybe my whole way and workflow is not the best?

## The objectiv

There are persons (column `name`) who have eaten different `fruit`'s at different `day`'s. And there is some more data (column `foo` and `bar`) I do not want to lose.

I want to **separate/split** the original data, **without loosing the additational data** (in `foo` and `bar`).
The **condition to separate** is the **number of unique fruits eaten at the specific days**.

That is the initial data

```
>>> df
   name  day       fruit  foo  bar
0   Tim    1       Apple  708   20
1   Tim    1       Apple  135  743
2   Tim    2       Apple  228  562
3  Anna    1      Banana  495  924
4  Anna    1  Strawberry  236  542
5   Bob    1  Strawberry  420  894
6   Bob    2       Apple   27  192
7   Bob    2        Kiwi  671  145
```

The separated **interim result** should look like this two `DataFrame`'s:

```
>>> two
   name  day       fruit  foo  bar
0  Anna    1      Banana  495  924
1  Anna    1  Strawberry  236  542
2   Bob    2       Apple   27  192
3   Bob    2        Kiwi  671  145

>>> non_two
   name  day       fruit  foo  bar
0   Tim    1       Apple  708   20
1   Tim    1       Apple  135  743
2   Tim    2       Apple  228  562
3   Bob    1  Strawberry  420  894
```

Example explanation in words: `Tim` ate just `Apple`'s at day `1` and `2`. It does not matter how many apples. It just matters that it is one unique fruit.

## What I have done so far

I did some `groupby()` magic to find out who and when have eaten two or less/more then two unique fruits.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

data = {'name': ['Tim', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
        'day': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry',
                  'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Kiwi'],
        'foo': rd.sample(range(1000), 8),
        'bar': rd.sample(range(1000), 8)
}

# That is the primary DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Explore the data
a = df[['name', 'day', 'fruit']].groupby(['name', 'day', 'fruit']).count().reset_index()
b = a.groupby(['name', 'day']).count()

# People who ate 2 fruits on specific days
two = b[(b.fruit == 2)].reset_index()
print(two)

# People who ate less or more then 2 fruits on specific days
non_two = b[(b.fruit != 2)].reset_index()
print(non_two)
```

## Here is my roadblocker

With the dataframes `two` and `non_two` I have the informations I want. Know I want to separate the initial dataframe based on that informations. I think `name` and `day` are the columns I should use to select and separate in the initial dataframe.

```
# filter mask
mymask = (df.name == two.name) & (df.day == two.day)

df_two = df[mymask]
df_non_two = df[~mymask]
```

But this does not work. The first line raise `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), so possible filter original `DataFrame`:

```
mymask = df.groupby(['name', 'day'])['fruit'].transform('nunique').eq(2)

df_two = df[mymask]
df_non_two = df[~mymask]

print (df_two)
   name  day       fruit  foo  bar
3  Anna    1      Banana  335   62
4  Anna    1  Strawberry  286  694
6   Bob    2       Apple  822  738
7   Bob    2        Kiwi  793  449
```